# How to use string interpolation on string.replace

Tags: c#

I created a method and would like to know how to use string interpolation with string.replace inside my method.

I looked through several how to's on Stack Overflow on its use but not with replace. I would like some guidance on how to accomplish this.

```
 private string CheckForEscapeStringInQuotesAndTrim(string csvDataValue)
 {
     if (Regex.IsMatch(csvDataValue, "[,\"\\r\\n]"))
     {
         return "\"" + csvDataValue.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
     }
     //trim any unnecessary whitespace
     return csvDataValue.Trim();
 }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The same way you do string interpolation without replace, `return $"\"{csvDataValue.Replace("\"", "\"\"")}\"";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use `csvDataValue.Replace("\"", "\"\"")` as an *interpolated expression* it will be resolved.

```
private string CheckForEscapeStringInQuotesAndTrim(string csvDataValue)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(csvDataValue, "[,\"\\r\\n]"))
    {
        return $"\"{csvDataValue.Replace("\"", "\"\"")}\"";
    }
    //trim any unnecessary whitespace
    return csvDataValue.Trim();
}
```